# railsでラベルを取得するほうほう

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

```
shop = Shop.first
# <Shop id: 1, name: "お店の名前", tel: "お店の電話番号">
```

このようなデータがあります。

`locals/ja.yml`にモデルのカラムに対応する表示用の名前をつけたのですが、これをフォーム以外で使うにはどうしたらよいのでしょうか。

```
shop.id.label
# => ID
shop.name.label
# => 店名
shop.tel.label
# => 電話番号
```

このように扱いたいのですが。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`.human_attribute_name` を利用してみてはいかがでしょうか？

```
Shop.human_attribute_name(:id)
Shop.human_attribute_name(:name)
Shop.human_attribute_name(:tel)
```